# Redmine: The entry or revision was not found in the repository

Tags: git, apache, redmine

I'm trying to access a git repository with Redmine.
Unfortunately, I'm not able to do this, here is the error given :

```
The entry or revision was not found in the repository.
```

Here is my configuration:

```
SCM: Git
Main Repository: Checked
Identifier: wide
Path to repository: /var/repos/git/wide
Path encoding: UTF-8
```

I tried several things. After cloning my non-bare repository into a bare repository, I tried these several paths:

```
/var/repos/git/wide
/var/repos/git/wide/.git
/var/repos/git/wide.git
/var/repos/git/wide.git/.git
```

I also tried to change the owner of my git repository to apache (as apache runs Redmine).

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: you need the first path `/var/repos/git/wide` to get this to work. Check the path if there is really an existant git repository (filesize). Also redmine takes some time (really) to get the repo up and working. A restart might help.

Comment: I already tried. but it's not working. And the path is a git repository.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this tutorial (on official redmine page)
[HowTo: easily integerate a (SSH secured) GIT repository into redmine](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Easily_integrate_a_%28SSH_secured%29_GIT_repository_into_redmine) some time ago with detailed command to execute and a quite detailed example. If you don't have a ssh secured GIT repository, ignore the statements regarding this.

In short (if you know the commands by mind) main things are:

- Folder for the repository the redmine user can read/write
- Cloning the repository as **MIRROR** (not *BARE*)!
- Set up your repository in redmine project settings without `.git` just the folder (full path)
- Adding a cronjob to automatically fetch the repository and update the data inside redmine

Hope this helps you

edit: The full tutorial written by myself

---

### HowTo: Easily integrate a (SSH secured) GIT repository into redmine

#### Scope

This HowTo will show how to integrate a GIT repository to your redmine project and how to keep the repository up to date.

#### Prerequisites

- The owner of your redmine-directory needs an SSH-Key and (reading) access to the repository you want to integrate in redmine.
- A directory to clone the GIT-repository is needed.
- Redmine must find the GIT-binaries, that means GIT must be installed. You can check this in redmine in the `administration > repositories` settings. If there is green checkmark everything is fine. If not you have to install GIT first, e.g. via `apt-get install`

Example configuration

To better understand this HowTo I will use the following configuration

- My owner of redmine is called `redmine`
- My redmine main directory is `/var/lib/redmine` and I will create a subdirectory `repos` there, where I clone the repositories. So the full path of this directory is `/var/lib/redmine/repos/`
- The URL of my repo is `git.my-url.com`, the name `my_repo`, so full URL is `git@git.my-url.com:my_repo`

#### Step 1: Clone the repositories

First we need to clone the repository as a **MIRROR** (not *BARE* !) repository. A mirror repository has no workfiles but only the commit information what is all we need for redmine.

We switch to redmine-user and clone the repository into the choosen directory.

```
sudo -su redmine
cd /var/lib/redmine/repos/
git clone --mirror git@git.my-url.com:my_repo my_repo
```

Now all repository information are on disk, but redmine don't knows anything about that. So in the next step we will change this.

#### Step 2: Introduce the repository to redmine

Inside redmine we open the "administration > project -> repositories" dialog. You can access this dialog also via "project -> settings -> repositories". There we add a new repository

> **Type**: GIT
>   **Main-repository**: check this if the cloned repository is you main repository, if not leave it unchecked.
>   **Name** (redmine intern): I suggest to choose the same name as the repository, e.g. `my_repo`
>   **Path**: Absolute path of the repository, e.g. `/var/lib/redmine/repos/my_repo`

Now redmine knows the repository. If you open the `repository`-tab inside your project you will see the repository tree, last commits and so on.

**Note**: When you open the dialog redmine fetchs all changeset *the local repository and the redmine database* since the last time anyone opend this dialog. Especially opening the dialog for the first time of a large repository may take very long. Don't cancel the progress, just let redmine work until it has finished. **Possible Fallacy**: When opening the dialog redmine **DOESN'T** fetch new commits out of GIT! This means that you will never see new commits inside redmine if you don't update the local GIT repository. For that we will write a cronjob in step 3.

#### Step 3: Adding a cronjob to fetch the GIT-repository

To keep the GIT repository automatically up to date we will add a cronjob. With the `--all` parameter we define to fetch all branches.

We open the user specified crontab for the user `redmine` and add a cronjob to fetch all branches every five minutes.

```
sudo -e -u redmine
```

and add this line

```
*/5 * * * * cd /var/lib/redmine/repos/my_repo && git fetch --all
```

Alternatively we can directly edit the `/etc/crontab`-file. If we do this we have to add the username of the repository-owner who should execute the commands.

```
nano /etc/crontab
```

and add this line

```
*/5 * * * * redmine cd /var/lib/redmine/repos/my_repo && git fetch --all
```

**NOTE** If you clone multiple repositories you have to add a crontab-line for every repository.